# Awk script to sum multiple column if value in column1 is duplicate

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

Need your help to resolve the below query.
I want to sum up the values for column3,column5,column6, column7,column9,column10 if value in column1 is duplicate.
Also need to make duplicate rows as single row in output file and also need to put the value of column1 in column 8 in output file

input file

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j
IN27201800024099|a|2.01|ad|5|56|6|rr|1|5
IN27201800023963|b|3|4|rt|67|6|61|ty|6
IN27201800024099|a|4|87|ad|5|6|1|rr|7.45
IN27201800024099|a|5|98|ad|5|6|1|rr|8
IN27201800023963|b|7|7|rt|5|5|1|ty|56
IN27201800024098|f|80|67|ty|6|6|1|4rght|765
```

output file

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k
IN27201800024099|a|11.01|190|ad|66|18|3|rr|20.45|IN27201800024099
IN27201800023963|b|10|11|rt|72|11|62|ty|62|IN27201800023963
IN27201800024098|f|80|67|ty|6|6|1|4rght|765|IN27201800024098
```

Tried below code, but it is not working and also no clue how to complete the code to get correct output

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} FNR==1 {a[$1]+= (f3[key]+=$3;f5[key]+=$5;f6[key]+=$6;f7[key]+=$7;f9[key]+=$9;f10[key]+=$10;)} input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Why not spread your script out across a few lines with white space so it's clear and readable instead of cramming it all onto 1 line where it's just a mush of characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"
}
NR==1 {
    print $0, "h"
    next
}
{
    keys[$1]
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum[$1,i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        printf "%s", key
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, sum[key,i]
        }
        print OFS key
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h
IN27201800023963|10|11|72|11|62|62|IN27201800023963
IN27201800024098|80|67|6|0|1|765|IN27201800024098
IN27201800024099|11.01|190|66|18|3|20.45|IN27201800024099
```

The above outputs the lines in random order, if you want them output in the same order as the key values were read in, it's just a couple more lines of code:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"
}
NR==1 {
    print $0, "h"
    next
}
!seen[$1]++ {
    keys[++numKeys] = $1
}
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum[$1,i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, sum[key,i]
        }
        print OFS key
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h
IN27201800024099|11.01|190|66|18|3|20.45|IN27201800024099
IN27201800023963|10|11|72|11|62|62|IN27201800023963
IN27201800024098|80|67|6|0|1|765|IN27201800024098
```

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton...suppose if we have column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,columns7 as column38, column39, column40, column42,column44 and column49 in inputfile then how to deal with it(also input file contains around 59 columns out of which need to sum on column,38,39,40,42,44,49). As currently in input file all column are in sequence from column 2 to coluimn7.